# If statement to check if a certain value is in array or a range of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello I am having difficulties working with arrays from a Google Spreadsheet, so I have the following code:

```
var statusCell = rows.getCell(i, statusColumn);
var ownerCell = rows.getCell(i, ownerColumn);

var owners = new Array ("Mark","Chris","Will","Amy");  

if(ownerCell.getValue() === "One of the values in the array(owners)") 
{statusCell.setValue('Claimed')};
```

All my cells have been specified and so on, and I have no problem, getting cells in specific locations and or setting them. But my problem here is that I would ideally have a range of some sort in a different sheet with names, but for now they can be listed in an array, like shown in the script.

Then I want to make an if statement, and check wether the "ownerCell" one of the values that are listed in the array. So ex. if the "ownerCell" = "Chris" then the if statement would continue, because it is one of the names listed in the array and then set the "statusCell" to be "Claimed". As seen in the script.

Maybe you can do something directly so you wouldn't have to compare, I don't know. Some advice would really help me out. Thanks alot :)

Comment: [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: And it'd be better to write in  `var owners = ["Mark","Chris","Will","Amy"];`

Comment: But as far as I can see here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp the indexOf only returns the index? So for "chris" that would be "1". I need to check if the value is there? Or am I misunderstanding something.

Comment: @WilliamLarsenBang `indexOf` returns `-1` if the value isn't found. So just check whether the result is not `-1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to test whether the value is found in the array. It returns `-1` when the value isn't found, the index if it is.

```
if (owners.indexOf(ownerCell.getValue()) != -1) {
  statusCell.setValue('Claimed');
}
```